# Using a Laravel 5 / Eloquent where statement to find an object's relational object

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have an object called 'Notification'. 'Notification' is related to another object called 'NotificationGroup' through a one to many relation (A NotificationGroup can own many Notifications). A 'NotificationGroup' belongs to another object called 'Organisation' in a similar way (An Organisation can own many NotificationGroups).

Using a where statement, would it be possible to grab all the Notifications that belong to an Organisation.

I apologise for the long-winded question, but I cannot find examples of this anywhere, nor if this type of thing is possible.

Comment: You can create a [hasManyThrough](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#has-many-through) relationship between Organisation and Notification.

Comment: Thanks Don'tPanic, that's exactly what I needed. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Don'tPanic's information, I used a 'hasManyThrough' relationship and created this statement.

```
$this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Notification', 'App\Models\NotificationGroup',  'organisation', 'notificationGroup')->get();
```